# Assign values from Table to a list

Tags: list-manipulation

I am trying to make a set of initial conditions - `{x0, y0, z0}` using transformation :

```
x0 = Ri Sin[th0] Cos[ph0]
y0 = Ri Sin[th0] Sin[ph0]
z0 = Ri Cos[th0]
```

I want to do it for a list of `th0` and `ph0` of unequal lengths. I do this :

```
Ri = 0.1
Table[{Ri Sin[th0] Cos[ph0], Ri Sin[th0] Sin[ph0], 
  Ri Cos[th0]} , {th0, 0.0, Pi, 45.0 Pi/180.0}, {ph0, 0.0, 2.0 Pi, 45.0 Pi/180.0}]
```

I get a list, but how can I assign the values to `{x0, y0, z0}`? Because I want to use them in next calculations, and consider all combinations of `th0` and `ph0` resulting in `{x0, y0, z0}` to be used as initial conditions.

Comment: `lst = Flatten[Table[ stuff , ... ], 1]` and access the list using `Part`.  For instance, `lst[[5,2]]` will be the $x$ coordinate of the fifth point (i.e. $x$ coordinate corresponding to some choice of $\theta$ and $\phi$).

Comment: {x0, y0, z0} = 
 Transpose@Flatten[Table[{Ri Sin[th0] Cos[ph0], Ri Sin[th0] Sin[ph0], Ri Cos[th0]}, {th0, 0.0, Pi, 45.0 Pi/180.0}, {ph0, 0.0, 2.0 Pi, 45.0 Pi/180.0}], 1]

Comment: To apply `f` to each `{x, y, z}` use `data = Flatten[Table[{Ri Sin[th0] Cos[ph0], Ri Sin[th0] Sin[ph0], Ri Cos[th0]}, {th0, 0.0, Pi, 45.0 Pi/180.0}, {ph0, 0.0, 2.0 Pi, 45.0 Pi/180.0}], 1]; f@@@data`

Comment: Screenshot so far: https://i.stack.imgur.com/LcvF2.png ; Also, I have borrowed `f@@@data` from the comment by Bob Hanlon.

Comment: unrelated, but just for a tiny bit of convenience, i'll mention the built-in constant `Degree`, which is numerically `Pi/180` (so that `45.0 Degree` is 45 degrees (in radians))

Comment: Thank you, all! This all works, and helps a lot!